# NET Core 8 DbGeometry Support

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, .net-core, geometry

I've been tasked to convert a .NET Framework 4.5 system to .NET Core 8. So I've created new .NET Core 8 versions of the existing projects.  Everything is moving along fine except for one thing. One of the SQL Server database fields is type Geometry. I'm having trouble with this field. I used the EF Core Power Tools to reverse engineer the table classes.  I used the Map spatial types option under Mapping to pick up the geometry field. That worked fine.

One line that is getting an error is this:

```
// Initialize CLR Types for SQL Server
SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

This gets the error:

> The name 'SqlServerTypes' does not exist in the current context

The new and old versions use the Nuget package `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.`

Another error occurs in this method:

```
    private static DbGeometry GetGeometry(string wkt)
    {
        DbGeometry result = null;

        try
        {
            result = DbGeometry.FromText(wkt, SRID);
        }
    }
```

It gives these errors:

> The name 'DbGeometry' does not exist in the current context
> The type or namespace name 'DbGeometry' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The final error involves this code:

```
        else
        {
            string wkt = jam.GetLineString(AppSettings.GeoLinePercision);
            tj.GEOM_LINWRK = GetGeometry(wkt);
        }
```

It gives the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry' to 'NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Geometry

The old version has the using statement: using `System.Data.Entity.Spatial;`  I can't find a similar using for NET CORE 8.

On that note, I see numerous posts on the web that NET Core doesn't support spatial types.  But some post are over half decade old. I can't believe the NET Core wouldn't support them by now. I've even tried making NET Core 6 versions of the projects but still get the same errors.

A co-worker mentioned that I might have to install a patch that allows Visual Studio 22 to recognize spatial types. I vaguely remember doing those several years ago for VS 19 or older.  If this is the fix I don't know where to get it.

Also, the previous version's database classes defined the geometry field as dbgeometry. That class has `using system.data.Entity.Spatial` statement.  The class generated by the EF Core extension defined it as Geometry and has a `enter code here`
`using nettopologysuite.geometries` statement.  One if the suggested fixes by VS says to add a reference to System.Data.Entity.dll. But from my understanding, that is a .NET Framework 4.5 dll.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When I upgraded from .NET Framework to .NET 6, I found no way to use SqlServerTypes, DbGeometry, System.Data.Entity.Spatial or System.Data.Entity.dll.

The solution that worked was to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite, and go with the Geometry class from NetTopologySuite. I got rid of everything using the System.Data namespace, and rebuilt the functions that used DbGeometry.